# How to add existing product into invoices as nested attributes in Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, nested-attributes

I have read about nested attributes in Rails, so far I found gems cocoon that have my needs to distributing form for nested attributes and can do all implementation so far. But I want to trying to add existing data product into invoices form as nested attributes by searching the product data with cocoon. What I should do to accomplish those form interaction in Rails?

Like this picture I guess for the example:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRICT.png)

**UPDATE**

Invoice.rb

```
class Invoice < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :products, inverse_of: :invoice
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ticket_details, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end
```

Product.rb

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :tax
  belongs_to :invoice
end
```

Comment: You should provide some of your code, for example: your models

Comment: Hi, I have updated my code models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For using [nested attributes](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) you need make changes in your models, views and controllers:

**Model:** Your models needs to specify *accepts_nested_attributes_for* (In your case change ticket_details for products)

```
class Invoice < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :products, inverse_of: :invoice
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :products, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end
```

**View:** Use the [fields_for](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for) to generate your products_attributes parameter

```
<%= form_for @invoice do |form| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :name %>
    <%= form.text_field :name, id: :user_name %>
  </div>

  <%= form.fields_for :products, @invoice.products do |product| %>
    <%= product.text_field :name %>
  <% end %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**Controller:** Permit the parameter products_attributes

```
def invoice_params
  params.require(:invoice).permit(:name, products_attributes: [:name, :id])
end
```

Comment: Yes, I've wrong declaring the model. In other case in views how to achieve if we want to choose from an existing product on invoice form, not only add new product in invoice?

Comment: form.fields_for :products, @invoice.products is going to give you all existing products related to invoice

Comment: I've declared #products_field = f.simple_fields_for :products, @invoice.products do |product| .nested_fields = product.text_field :code. But why seems like not show the form fields_for products?